# C binary search tree insertion by char element

Tags: c, char, binary-search-tree, insertion

I have to create a binary search tree by inserting in every node data about pharmaceutical drug . The nodes are sorted by a char NAME .I've got an error , a segmentation fault error at `strcmp(name,(*parent)->name) < 0` .Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct date
{
    int dd,mm,yyyy;
};
typedef struct node
{
    char name[50];
    float price;
    int amount;
    struct date date_rel;
    struct date date_exp;
    struct node *left , *right;
} node;
node *insert_node(node **parent,char name[])
{
    node *current = NULL;
    if(*parent == NULL)
    {
        current = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(current->name,name);
        printf("\nPrice =");
        scanf("%f",&current->price);
        printf("\nAmount =");
        scanf("%d",&current->amount);
        printf("\nRelease date =");
        scanf("%d.%d.%d",&current->date_rel.dd,&current->date_rel.mm,&current->date_rel.yyyy);
        printf("\nExpiration date =");
        scanf("%d.%d.%d",&current->date_exp.dd,&current->date_exp.mm,&current->date_exp.yyyy);
        *parent = current;
    }
    else
    {
        if(strcmp(name,(*parent)->name) < 0)
        {
            (*parent)->left = insert_node(&(*parent)->left,name);
        }
        else
        {
            (*parent)->right = insert_node(&(*parent)->right,name);
        }
    }
    return *parent;
}

int main()
{
    node *root = NULL;
    char name[50] ;
    int total_prod;
    printf("The total number of medicines is:");
    scanf("%d",&total_prod);
     while(total_prod != 0)
     {
         printf("Name =");
         scanf("%s",name);
         insert_node(&root,name);
         total_prod--;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's because you don't initialize the `left` and `right` pointers when `*parent` is `NULL`. As they are uninitialized they will have an *indeterminate* value, and in reality it will be seemingly random, and most likely not equal to `NULL` which leads you to use them as valid pointers and you will have *undefined behavior* and get the crash.

Before the `*parent = current` assignment you need to initialize the `left` and `right` pointers of `current` to `NULL`.